# Display images from directory?

Tags: php

I have a code to display images from folder which is working fine but in Google chrome it's showing one extra box like image.How I can fix this ?

Here is my code:

```
<?php                  
      $files = glob("photogallery/thumb/group1/*.jpg*"); 

      for ($i=0; $i<=count($files); $i++) 
      { 
         $num = $files[$i]; 
         echo '<a href="photo_view.php?gn=1" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="'.$num.'"  width="100px" height="100px" alt=""></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
      }

?>
```

Comment: change the for condition to `for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)`. Notice I removed `=` from the condition

Comment: And also remove the last `*` from your glob call, its not needed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `count()` is going to return the total number of items in your zero-indexed array.  That means if your `$files` array has 10 items in it, the lowest index is 0 and the highest index is 9.

Your comparison of `$i<=count($files)` means that `$i` would go from 0 to 10 (11 total items) in this example.

I recommend using `foreach` anyway.  It's a more generic way of iterating over a collection, and allows for sparse arrays.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // use the $file variable here in your echo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                  
      $files = glob("photogallery/thumb/group1/*.jpg*"); 

      for ($i=0; $i<=count($files); $i++) 
      { 
if(trim($files[$i])){
         $num = $files[$i]; 
         echo '<a href="photo_view.php?gn=1" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="'.$num.'"  width="100px" height="100px" alt=""></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
}
      }

?>
```